# Add delay to video stream?

Tags: camera, video

I am working on an art project where I need to use the raspberry to display its camera feed but with a five second delay,  I have seen some thoughts on this using the SHELL but as I have been using a little python to (try to) get this to work so far I am wondering if there is a python solution to this problem I have not come across?  Any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean delaying video to the preview display, or to something else like a file or network receiver? The former is non-trivial, while the latter is quite easy.

Comment: Sadly, I mean to delay the video to the preview display.   I found a couple threads related to this topic :https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=63739

Comment: I could get neither of the two solutions offered to function correctly although I feel as if the mogabe one got me close, but I couldn't figure out a way to get the created file to open, I think it may be a packaging problem, but my bash skills are more abysmal than my python skills.

Answer (score -1):

If using python

```
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I don't think that this really addresses the OP's intention (who however did not respond to the inquerry).

Comment: I believe that this would work in python if I were using it to create and write over several video files and have the playback staggered one behind the recordings, but my python isn't proficient enough at this point for me to rely exclusively on it at the expense of other option.  Will still attempt of course tho :)